# Edited guest xml with 'virsh edit' to add ttyS0 but ttyS0 is not added

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, xen, qemu

I am facing the errors in `/var/log/messages` like:

```
Feb 19 20:19:42  guest-dp init: serial (ttyS0) main process (608881) terminated with status 1
Feb 19 20:19:42 guest-dp init: serial (ttyS0) main process ended, respawning
```

I want to get rid of the 'respawn' error as above.

I used `virsh edit <guest>`. I edited the file and used `virsh define` to define the file again. Once done, I rebooted the guest (`virsh reboot <guest>`).

I have edited xml file for this guest with the code:

```
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
```

But after the reboot, the error is still present. I need to find the solution without editing the `grub.conf` file.

Comment: Your `<guest>` were interpreted by the system as html tags, thus they were filtered out. This was the main reason, why your post was unclear. I fixed it, and I think now it has a good chance for a reopening (it is decided by a vote, not by me alone), but in any case, please be more careful with your posts in the future.

Comment: If your VM doesn't have a serial port, why is your OS configured to try to use one? I think you should look into that bit.

Comment: A reboot doesn't cause the VM to be redefined (the kvm process does not terminate). You need to shutdown and start the VM.

Comment: Michael Hampton I am not sure how was the initial installation done ? Now I want to know if serial port S0 was not there then how come after installation I would get errors like "serial (ttyS0) main process (608881) terminated with status 1". What makes it to throw an error of such a kind??